# ng-repeat to show output in separate columns

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Can anyone direct me how to display values of array in separate columns with ng-repeat? Please note that fields are dynamically generated and I cannot hardcode name of fields like tran.id, or tran.firstname....
thanks

My html is:

```
<tr ng-repeat="tran in trans">                       
     <td>{{ tran }}</td>   
</tr>
```

My JS code is:

```
$scope.displayTrans = function(){
        $http.get("model/selecttrans.php")
        .then(function(response) {  

            console.log(response.data);
            $scope.trans = response.data;

        }); 

    }
```

and my PHP code is:

```
<?php   

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM trans";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);  
    $stmt->execute();

    $total = $stmt->rowCount();

    if ($total > 0 ) {

        while ($row = $stmt->fetchObject()) {

            $output[] = $row; 

        }
    } else {
        $output = 'No data';
    }

    echo json_encode($output);
```

I am getting following output in my console:

```
[…]
​
0: {…}
​​
"$$hashKey": "object:15"
​​
email: null
​​
firstname: "Aziz"
​​
id: "19"
​​
lastname: "Virani"
​​
password: "12345"
​​
__proto__: Object { … }
​
1: {…}
​​
"$$hashKey": "object:16"
​​
email: "test@test.edu"
​​
firstname: "Test"
​​
id: "32"
​​
lastname: "Result"
​​
password: "test"
​​
__proto__: Object { … }
​
length: 2
​
__proto__: Array []
```

and following output in my browser:

```
{"id":"19","lastname":"Virani","password":"12345","firstname":"Aziz","email":null}
{"id":"32","lastname":"Result","password":"test","firstname":"Test","email":"test@test.edu"}
```

Can any one suggest me how can I display output in separate columns as mentioned below:

```
id   |  lastname  | password
32   |  Result    | test
```

Please ignore validation here like password should be hashed or md5 etc.....

I can easily get data by typing {{ tran.id }} or {{ tran.firstname }} but these fields are dynamically generated and i cannot hardcode fields name....

thank you
Aziz

Comment: thank you @Tyler, i did some research, tried (key, value) in ng-repeat....tried nested ng-repeat.... modified my controller and then posted question here.......

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the way to display output....

Earlier I used nested ng-repeat with (key, value) with table row  property but here on some other blog i found that nested ng-repeat works with table data  so I updated my code and everything works cool....